# NSUndoManager to add and remove textVIew as a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, nsundomanager

How can i use NSUndo manager to add or remove a subview maybe a textview in the view controller.I have seen many examples for textview text undo redo .But cannot found how to add or remove a view form a view using nsundomanager.
Can anybody help me out please..

Comment: What's wrong with the documentation instructions here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/RegisteringUndo.html ?

Comment: From the above link it is given only to change the values .But i completely have to remove the object ,i am not able to get how to do it.

Comment: You can register any method to execute the undo operation, and have any code in that method. So you can have the method add and remove objects. (That's how I understand the docs, at least.)

Comment: Could you give me some example to delete a subview from view using undo manager.It would be very generous of you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get to write anything with NSUndoManager yet. But feel free to just experiment and see what works - it'll teach you better than anything else :-)

Answer (score 0):

what I did to remove a subview from a view using NSUndoManager is saving a "stack" of the subviews in a NSMutableArray.
When the shake gesture is detected and the undoManager is called for undoing, I check if `[self.undoManager isUndoing]` and, if that's the case, I call the method that removes the last subview from that array from the current view.

On a note aside, to "Redo" the action, you have to call `prepareWithInvocationTarget` again from the method that is undoing, so that it will know how to handle the Redo action in case the user wants to redo. To manage the Redo, I save the point where the subview was added, and if the user wants to redo, I add it again in the same place.